# Drupal - Unable to get result from db_query

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, drupal-7

I have written below code in drupal module.

```
echo '<pre>';
$data = db_query("SELECT uid, name, status, created, access FROM {users} u WHERE uid <> 0 LIMIT 50 OFFSET 0");
print_r($data);
die;
```

But it is not giving me users data it is giving me below output:

```
DatabaseStatementBase Object
(
[dbh] => DatabaseConnection_mysql Object
    (
        [needsCleanup:protected] => 
        [target:protected] => default
        [key:protected] => default
        [logger:protected] => 
        [transactionLayers:protected] => Array
            (
            )

        [driverClasses:protected] => Array
            (
                [SelectQuery] => SelectQuery
            )

        [statementClass:protected] => DatabaseStatementBase
        [transactionSupport:protected] => 1
        [transactionalDDLSupport:protected] => 
        [temporaryNameIndex:protected] => 0
        [connectionOptions:protected] => Array
            (
                [database] => aaldev
                [username] => root
                [password] => 
                [host] => localhost
                [port] => 
                [driver] => mysql
                [prefix] => Array
                    (
                        [default] => 
                    )
            )

        [schema:protected] => 
        [prefixes:protected] => Array
            (
                [default] => 
            )

        [prefixSearch:protected] => Array
            (
                [0] => {
                [1] => }
            )

        [prefixReplace:protected] => Array
            (
                [0] => 
                [1] => 
            )
    )

[queryString] => SELECT uid, name, status, created, access FROM users u WHERE uid <> 0 LIMIT 50 OFFSET 0
)
```

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your query is correct, and [Drupal documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/1251174), you have a `fetchAll()` method:

```
   $data = db_query("SELECT uid, name, status, created, access FROM {users} u WHERE uid <> 0 LIMIT 50 OFFSET 0");
   $data->fetchAll();
```

Retrieve all records into an indexed array of stdClass objects.